# Azure Cosmos DB: 'ToString' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

Getting error when Azure CosmosDB's SQL ToString system function is being used to fetch data from Cosmos container using `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient` client.
Strange but queries are running fine on the Azure portal, Data explorer tab.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-tostring

```
Assembly Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core, Version=1.9.1.0

Project .Net Core 2.2
```

Queries

```
select ToString(c) FROM c where c.id = 1
select value ToString(c) FROM c where c.id = 1
```

**Error**

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: 'Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":13,"end":21},"code":"SC2005","message":"'ToString' is not a recognized built-in function name."}]}'
```

**UPDATE 1**

Code is given below

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(string sqlExpression, string collectionName)
{
    var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxItemCount = 100 };

    IDocumentQuery<T> query = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName), sqlExpression, option)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var items = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
        results.AddRange(items);
    }

    return results;
}


    string sqlExpression = $"SELECT ToString(C) FROM C WHERE C.id = {id}";
    var jsons = await this.GetItemsAsync<string>(sqlExpression, collectionName);
```

**UPDATE 2**

***Actual JSON***

```
[
  {
    "id": "79332",
    "pk": "2020081416PM",
    "key": "134869d8-f291-4c96-affe-266d86ae95b8",
    "version": 3,
    "_self": "dbs/ddadfZp5AA==/colls/fZp5AJhvYZY=/docs/fZp5AJhvYZZ6AAAAAAAAAQ==/",
    "_etag": "\"1f00dsd475d-0000-0200-0000-5f5f6edc0000\"",
    "_ts": 1600089820
  }
]
```

***Expected result***

```
[
    "{\"id\":\"79332\",\"pk\":\"2020081416PM\",\"key\":\"134869d8-f291-4c96-affe-266d86ae95b8\",\"version\":3,\"_self\":\"dbs\\/fZp5AA==\\/colls\\/fZp5AJhvYZY=\\/docs\\/fZp5AJhvYZZ6AAAAAAAAAQ==\\/\",\"_etag\":\"\\\"1f00475d-0000-0200-0000-5f5f6edc0000\\\"\",\"_ts\":1600089820}"
]
```

Comment: I appreciate all the users who spared there precious time to react on my question, but I am unsure why you down voted it. I will appreciate if you can also provide the reason of down vote.

Comment: Please show the .NET code to understand what you're trying to achieve? If you just want a string version of the value, it would be simpler to just call `.ToString()' on the result in C#.

Comment: @Noah I have added the code, all I want just to convert stored complete JSON to string while fetching it from the DB.

Comment: Please also show an example source item from Cosmos and the desired result item after fetched.

Comment: As the error message states, ToString() is not a system function in Cosmos DB. You cannot use this in a query. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @NoahStahl added the actual and expected result.

Comment: @MarkBrown may I ask why I cannot use 'ToString' in query at one place but not at another place, as I mentioned I am able to execute the very same query in Azure portal's Data Explorer section.

Comment: Replace <T> with <dynamic> in your query

Comment: @MarkBrown same error with <dynamic>.

Comment: Did you remove the ToString from your query?

Comment: @markbrown no, that's what I need to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221467/discussion-between-ankit-and-mark-brown).

Comment: Please remove ToString from your query. As the error states, this is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the assembly (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core) to Version 2.11.6 and it solves the problem.